# Dropping SQL tables

Tags: sql

I started to learn mySQL and a thought came to mind, I always see memes about databases and dropping tables, and how much of a problem such an even event can cause. My question is why would someone working in a software development environment ever decide to drop a table or even an entire scheme for that matter?

Comment: In general, you wouldn't do this as part of regular operations.  For software development, it might be part of creating a test environment.  In that case, I would think the dropping would be at the database level rather than the table level.

Comment: holy moly... these memes about sql injections. the point is that if you dont handle user input properly, user can drop your tables

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons, the main ones that come to mind:

1. As part of a roll back, you migrated something to the production environment which had bugs or shouldn't have been deployed yet. In order to get back to the previous state you'd need to drop the new table.
2. As part of clean up: legacy parts of the database which you no longer need, old table partitions with already archived data, user schemas of people no longer working for the company.